# Question on group actions

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions

Here's what I need to show:

> Consider the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation. In other words,
>   if $g,a \in G$, then the action of $g$ on $a$ is defined by $g*a =
>  gag^{-1}$. Then show that if $G$ is not an abelian group, there is an
>   orbit of order at least $2$.

Here's my attempt:

Suppose that $\mathcal{O} _{s} =\{s\}$ for all $s\in G$. Thus, we must have $gsg^{-1}=s$ for all $g,s\in G$. Let $a,b \in G$ be arbitrary. Then $a=bab^{-1}$ and $b=aba^{-1}$.
Now, $$\begin{align} 
ab &= (bab^{-1})(aba^{-1}) \\
      &= ba(b^{-1}ab)a^{-1} \\
      &= ba(bab^{-1})a^{-1} \\
      &=baaa^{-1} \\
      &=ba.
\end{align}$$
Since $a,b \in G$ were arbitrary, this means $G$ is abelian which contradicts our hypothesis.

Is this proof okay?

Comment: Seems correct to me :-)

Comment: Easier: we have $gs=sg$ for all $g,s\in G$. So $G$ is abelian. So the rest is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might want to indicate why $\mathcal O_s=\{s\}\,,\forall s\in G$, other than just that it has order $1$.  I know it's trivial,  but perhaps mention that always  $s\in\mathcal O_s$, because of the fact that $e*s=s\,,\forall s$.  (I understand it's a general fact about group actions.)  However,  it's up to you.

On the other hand,  when $gsg^{-1}=s\,,\forall g,s\in G$, we *immediately* have that $gs=sg$, and hence the group is abelian.

Finally,  in the middle of your proof, I noticed that $b^{-1}ab$ gets replaced by $bab^{-1}$.  This might not be true.  To correct it, note that $b^{-1}ab=b^{-1}a{(b^{-1})}^{-1}=a$, by assumption.